# Symfony admin generator, link to filtered result

Tags: symfony1, filter, admin-generator

i have an admin generator for the folowing model:

```
#schema.yml
Author:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Book:
  columns:
    authorId: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    title: { type: string(512), notnull: true }
    content: { type: string(512), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Author: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: authorId, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Books}
```

I have gererated 2 pages with corresponding with each table

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend Author
php symfony doctrine:generate-admin backend Book
```

Now i want in the author view a link to his books.
What is the best way to do that ?
My try is a custom link that pre-selects filters, but i dont know how to do that.

```
#generator.yml for Author
# ...
    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:
      list:
        display: [id, name, _booksLink]
      filter:  ~
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

and

```
<!-- modules/author/templates/_booksLink.php -->
<a href="<?= link_to('book?author_id='.$author->getId()) ?>"><!-- how to select filter? -->
  See <?= $author->getName() ?> books
</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This lecture answers your question (slide 39 and 40):
http://www.slideshare.net/jcleveley/working-with-the-admin-generator

**in your actions.class php add:**

```
class AuthorActions extends AutoAuthorActions
{
  public function executeViewBooks($request) { 
    $this->getUser()->setAttribute( 'book.filters',   
    array('authorId' => $request->getParameter('id')), 'admin_module' ); 
    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('book')); 
  }
}
```

Note about the case: The field name matches the case defined in the schema. Eg: if you have `authorId` in the schema, you must write `authorId` in the function above (line 5). If you have `author_id` in the schema, you must write `author_id` in the function. Also, The module names are always lowercase with underscores (eg: `schema : MyBooks -> module name: my_books`).

**In your generator.yml**

```
list: 
  object_actions:
    _edit: ~
    _delete: ~
    viewPhones: { label: View books, action: viewBooks }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for fixing it, I'm always using the underscore notation by convention, I forgot there are other notation possible,

Comment: Good idea, I've been using a hackier way to achieve this till now.